# HIBERNATE : TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query after entityManager.createNativeQuery()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, struts

I'm working on a project using Struts, Spring and Hibernate. After clicking on a button, the Struts action leads me through a DS and DAO, in which I try to call a native query to update the DB. Here is the error trace:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
>
> at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:48)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
>
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
>
> at $Proxy496.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.my.project.MyDAO.unsubscribe(MyDAO.java:307)
>
> at com.my.project.MyDS.unsubscribe(MyDS.java:507)
>
> at com.my.project.MyDS.updateValue(MyDS.java:784)
>
> at com.my.project.MyAction.handleUpdate(MyAction.java:235)

**MyDAO :**

```
public class MyDAO extends
    AbstractDAOGenericImpl<MyEntity> {

    /** Entity Manager */
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
   private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public int unsubscribe(String entityId) throws JrafDaoException {
        StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
        strQuery.append("update MYENTITY set SUBSCRIBE=:subscribe where ENTITY_ID=:entity_id");

        final Query myQuery = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(strQuery.toString(), MyEntity.class);
        myQuery.setParameter("subscribe", "N");
        myQuery.setParameter("entity_id", entityId);

        try {
            return myQuery.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In **MyDS :**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("MyDAO")
private MyDAO myDao;

@Transactional(readOnly = false, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
public int unsubscribe(String entityId) throws JrafDomainException {
    return myDao.unsubscribe(entityId);
}
```

**MyAction :**

```
public class MyAction extends DispatchAction {

    private MyDS myDS;

    // ...

    private ActionForward handleUpdate(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        MyForm myForm = (MyForm) form;
        myDS.unsubscribe(myForm.getEntityId());
    }
}
```

And **application-context-spring.xml :**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Enterprise layer's dependencies -->

    <bean id="springLocator"
        class="com.jraf.bootstrap.locator.SpringLocator">
    </bean>

    <!-- To precise the persistence configuration name file -->
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>/META-INF/persistence-web.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- EntityManagerFactory definition : JPA one -->
    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager"
            ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <!-- TransactionManager JPA one -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>

    <!-- EntityManagerFactory definition : JPA one -->
    <bean id="myEmf2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit2" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Transaction Manager definition : JPA one-->
    <bean id="myTxManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf2" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Enable annotation usage for transaction -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">      
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1" />      
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1" />      
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="1" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="myDS" class="com.my.internal.MyDS">
        <property name="myDao" ref="MyDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the annotation usage (bean injection for instance) -->
    <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

I'm working on an existing project which is why the unsubscribe function already exists and uses a native query instead of a HQL one. But maybe I should use it instead...?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you getting `myDS`? Are you injecting it into action class, or you instantiate it yourself?

Comment: @PredragMaric It's injected by Spring, look at the end of application-context-spring.xml

Comment: I meant `myDS` in `MyAction` class. Not `myDao` in `MyDS` class/bean. Specifically, in line `myDS.unsubscribe(myForm.getEntityId())`, where does `myDS` come from?

Comment: Well `myDS` is injected there too, and in my **actions-dependencies** file I declare it : `<property name="communicationPreferences" ref="communicationPreferencesDS" />`

Comment: And `MyDAO` reference comes from a line in **application-context-spring** that I forgot to include : `<import resource="classpath:ioc/0-ref-commons-enterpriselayer-dependencies.xml" />`. This file contains the declaration of `MyDAO`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue.
Adding

```
tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
```

to your spring context xml will resolve the issue.